# Selecting schema configuration in Postgres with doctrine 2

Tags: mysql, postgresql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, dbal

I've got a complex question, I hope you will help me.

I'm using Doctrine DBAL in my application because I would like to make it works in Postgres and Mysql.

The problem is that I want to switch over the 5 schemas that I have.

For example I would to do this thing :

1. Action 1 --> Select schema 1
2. Action 2 --> Make a SQL request like this : "SELECT * FROM users"
3. Action 3 --> Select schema 2
4. Action 4 --> Make an other SQL request like this "SELECT * FROM users"

What I don't want to do :

1. Action 1 --> Make a SQL request like this : "SELECT * FROM
   schema1.users"
2. Action 2 --> Make an other SQL request like this
   "SELECT * FROM schema2.users"

What I tried (but don't work =S):

```
    $connection->getConnection()->exec("SET SEARCH_PATH schema1");
    $stmt = $connection->getConnection()->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
```

Is anyone have an idea how I can solve my problem ?
I will be very thankful if you could bring me some help.

Thank you.

Freezer

Answer (score 1):

I found where the problem was.

I did a mistake with my code >_<

Here is the code that work :

```
$connection->getConnection()->exec("SET SEARCH_PATH TO schema1");
$stmt = $connection->getConnection()->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
```

Thank you